# woocommerce cart is not functioning on more than 3 variations.?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the website from the client for his food services. well, I have used woo-commerce it works fine with no variations and with at least 3 variations but on 3 variations take 1 min to add items on the cart. but when I use 4 variations it keeps load too long and in the end after 10 to 15 minutes give error wp-DB time execute more than 240s. I even increased the time from phpmyadmin but nothing is resolved. I am quite sure something is wrong with woo-commerce but no idea what and how will it be resolved. Thanks

Comment: Edited main post with valid reason I identified not working. still guessing hack to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`||`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) operator means that it is enough to have only one condition be true so the whole `... || ...` statement becomes true. If you want that all conditions have to be met you need to use the `AND` operator.

```
$validName = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]*$/', $name);
$validPrice = preg_match('/^[0-9][1-3]*$/', $price);
$validWeight = preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $weight);
$validTemp = preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $temp);

if ($validName AND $validPrice AND $validWeight AND $validTemp) {
    // ... do something
}
```